# "se eu tiver tido feito" está gramaticalmente correto, seguindo à Norma Culta?

Tags: gramática, verbos, conjugações

Eu estava fazendo paralelos com conjugações do indicativo com do subjuntivo:

> Eu quis fazer isso
>
> Se eu tiver quisto fazer isso
>
> Se eles tivessem quisto fazer isso

> Eles irão à festa
>
> Se eles irem à festa.
>
> Se eles fossem à festa

> Vós estáveis andando de carro?
>
> Se nós tivermos estado andando de carro, quando é que isso te cornece?
>
> Se nós tivéssemos estado andando de carro, quando é que isso te concerne?

> Tu tinhas feito isso para quê?
>
> Se eu tiver tido feito isso, não te teria contado por um motivo.
>
> Se eu tivesse tido feito isso, não te teria contado por um motivo.

Porém, estou em dúvida se o penúltimo e último estão correto ou não.

Estão eles corretos, seguindo à Norma Culta? Digo seguindo à Norma Culta, porque num poema, por exemplo, escreveria independentemente da resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os dois últimos versos estão incorretos de acordo com a Norma Culta, pois há pleonasmo¹ neles.

O verbo "ter" nas duas situações é completamente inútil. Pelo que pude notar, a única função dele, ao ser aplicado, é definir o tempo verbal da frase. No entanto, isso pode ser feito também pelo verbo sucessor (na terceira estrofe) e antecessor (na quarta estrofe).

Observe como as frases ficariam quando completamente corretas de acordo com a Norma Culta (houve correção de outros elementos também, como o tempo verbal e a regência de um verbo):

> Se nós estivermos andando de carro, quando isso te cornece?

> Se nós estivéssemos andando de carro, quando isso te concerne?

e

> Se eu tiver feito isso, não te contarei por um motivo.

> Se eu tivesse feito isso, não teria te contado por um motivo.

Além do pleonasmo do verbo "ter", há alguns outros erros, sendo eles:

- Pleonasmo em "quando *é que* isso te concerne?". Não há necessidade do "é que" para que a frase tenha sentido completo.
- Erro de regência em "não *te teria* contado por um motivo". O correto seria "não teria te contado", pois o pronome "te" está regido pelo verbo "contar".
- Tempo verbal mal utilizado no penúltimo verso da última estrofe.

¹ [Pleonasmo](https://fasam.edu.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Manual-de-Reda%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-Estilo-Estad%C3%A3o.pdf) (verificar pág. 219).

Comment: "Se nós tivermos estado andando de carro" é mais no passado do que "se nós estivermos andando de carro". "eu fiz" → "se eu tiver feito", "eu fizera" → "se eu tiver tido feito"; "se eu tiver tido feito" está mais no passado do que "se eu tiver feito". Não estou dizendo que estás errado, mas acho que não entendeste,

Comment: Entendi sim, mas a sua afirmação não é verdadeira. Em primeiro lugar, não há como ser "mais no passado" que outra frase se está incorreto. "Se nós tivermos estado andando" não tem qualquer concordância e, portanto, não existe. Em segundo lugar, o verbo "ter", quando utilizado corretamente, apenas define o tempo verbal daquele trecho e, portanto, não há como ser "mais no passado" que outra frase com o mesmo sentido.

Comment: agoooooooora eu entendi. Obrigado. Então o máximo no passado é "se eu tiver feito" e "se eu estiver andando"?

Comment: No modo subjuntivo, sim.

Comment: @Chano: eu recentemente li que "as plantas tinham sido regadas" está correto. Se essa frase está correta, "ter + havido + part." ou "haver + tido + part." não poderia estar correto? Site: https://mundoeducacao.uol.com.br/gramatica/flexao-dos-verbos-nas-locucoes.htm